# stream_socket_client() failed since PHP 5.6.8 on XAMPP 5.6.8 on OS X

Tags: php, email, ssl, xampp, phpmailer

I just updated my XAMPP development rig from 1.7.3 to the newest version 5.6.8 for OS X. This updates PHP from 5.3.1 to 5.6.8. It breaks PHPMailer that send visitor enquiry via SMTP on SSL connection (not TLS) to my hosting site mail server. The problem is my hosting site only uses self signed certificate to authentication. this has no effect with the older XAMPP. But with the newest one, the function `stream_socket_client` that PHPMailer use for SMTP generate this error:

```
SSL operation failed with code 1.
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:
SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

This is what i have done

1. Modify PHPMailer to accept SSL context options
   PHP Mailer `send` function dont accept SSL context options yet, although the internal SMTP `connect` function has optional parameter for it. Also I unsuppress error message for the function `stream_socket_client`. I use this option:

```php
$mail->SMTPOption = array( 'smtp' => array(
'verify_peer' => false, 
'verivy_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true) );
```

But this has no effect, OpenSSL still raises above message.

2. Add openssl.cafile and openssl.capath property in php.ini. It still does not work.
3. PHPMailer Debug output just has this content

> ```
>  Connection: opening to ssl://wates.idwebhost.com:465, t=300, 
>  opt=array ( 'smtp' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 
>  'verivy_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
>  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>  SMTP connect() failed.
> ```

Please guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently I use older version of PHPMailer. After update to 5.2.10 version, the problem is solved.